# Convergence of a series implying harmonic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, harmonic-numbers

I have a question concerning the following series :
$$
(H_{2}-1)+(H_{3}-1)\left(1-\frac{H_{2}}{2}\right)+(H_{4}-1)\left(1-\frac{H_{2}}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{H_{3}}{3}\right)+(H_{5}-1)\left(1-\frac{H_{2}}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{H_{3}}{3}\right)\left(1-\frac{H_{4}}{4}\right)+\ldots$$
Which can be rewritten as :
$$
(H_{2}-1)+\sum_{n=3}^{N}\left(H_{n}-1\right)\left[\prod_{j=2}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{H_{j}}{j}\right)\right]
$$
With : 
$$H_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$$ 
When $N$ tends to $+\infty$, this sum converges to 1.
Do you have an idea to prove this ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: serie $\to$ series

Comment: $H_2 - 1 = 1 - 2\cdot\bigl(1 - \frac{H_2}{2}\bigr)$. Now $$-2\biggl(1 - \frac{H_2}{2}\biggr) + (H_3 - 1)\biggl(1 - \frac{H_2}{2}\biggr) = (H_3 - 3)\biggl(1 - \frac{H_2}{2}\biggr) = -3\biggl(1 - \frac{H_2}{2}\biggr)\biggl(1 - \frac{H_3}{3}\biggr).$$ Can you see a pattern emerge?

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. in fact, this serie can be rewritten as : $$1-n\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{H_{k}}{k}\right)$$. I have still to prove that the product tends to 1 when n tend to $+\infty \ldots$

Comment: the product tends to 0 sorry